# copy calendar entries from one calendar to another via apple script throws error

Tags: applescript, ical

i am trying to copy ical entries from one calendar to another using the following script:

```
tell application "iCal"
    set localEvents to events of calendar "Privat"
    set remoteEvents to events of calendar "owncloud"
    repeat with theEvent in localEvents
        if theEvent is not in remoteEvents then
            copy theEvent to end of remoteEvents
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

it throws the following error, that i do not understand:

```
error "«class wrev» id \"AEBA9736-5B3B-48D3-9DCA-80577709EAB5\" of
«class wres» id \"BAB254DB-3CC3-4383-B2E0-C8135EA5F65C\" of
application \"iCal\" kann nicht in Typ vector umgewandelt werden."
number -1700 from «class wrev» id
"AEBA9736-5B3B-48D3-9DCA-80577709EAB5" of «class wres» id
"BAB254DB-3CC3-4383-B2E0-C8135EA5F65C" to vector
```

what does it mean and how can i get the script working?

Comment: Doesn't an event get a new id if it's moved into a different calendar? In this case `if theEvent is not in remoteEvents` will always be true.

Comment: so how can i copy new events, without re-copying events that have been copied before? this script is supposed to run once every day.

Comment: What prevents you from creating the events in the target calendar directly?

Comment: the owncloud calendar is on a caldav server (owncloud) and (therefore?) not available for syncing with iSync.app.this script is only part of a sync-script that first starts iSync to sync my phone with the privat calendar and then copy the events to the owncloud calendar.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have so far. All works ok, except for my duplicate check. Just receiving tell statement for "Event Discarded: Old.". When this is not the case. Any Help?

```
to getRecurrenceTermination(startDate, recurrenceString)
set olddel to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ";"
set tItems to text items of recurrenceString
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "="
set d to 0
set untl to missing value
repeat with anItem in tItems

    set parts to text items of anItem
    set sec to word 3 of anItem

    if (offset of "FREQ=" in anItem) > 0 then
        if (offset of "WEEKLY" in anItem) > 0 then
            set d to 7
        else if (offset of "DAILY" in anItem) > 0 then
            set d to 1
        else if (offset of "MONTHLY" in anItem) > 0 then
            set d to 31
        end if
    else if (offset of "INTERVAL=" in anItem) > 0 then
        set d to d * sec
    else if (offset of "COUNT=" in anItem) > 0 then
        set d to d * sec
    else if (offset of "UNTIL=" in anItem) > 0 then
        set untl to current date
        set untl's year to text 1 thru 4 of sec
        set untl's month to text 5 thru 6 of sec
        set untl's day to text 7 thru 8 of sec
        set untl's hours to text 10 thru 11 of sec
        set untl's minutes to text 12 thru 13 of sec
        set untl's seconds to text 13 thru 14 of sec
    end if
end repeat
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to olddel

if untl is missing value then
    if d is not 0 then
        set finalDate to startDate + (d * days)
    else
        set finalDate to startDate + (1000 * days)
    end if
else
    set finalDate to untl
end if
return finalDate
end getRecurrenceTermination

tell application "iCal"

set TheCalendars to name of calendars

set theSourceCalendar to ""
set theDestinationCalendar to ""

choose from list TheCalendars with title "Please select a source calendar" without empty selection allowed
set theSourceCalendar to result as string

if theSourceCalendar is "" then
    --do nothing
else

    set theOtherCals to {}
    repeat with anItem in TheCalendars
        if (anItem as string) is not (theSourceCalendar as string) then set theOtherCals to theOtherCals & anItem
    end repeat

    choose from list theOtherCals with title "Please select a destination calendar" without empty selection allowed
    set theDestinationCalendar to result as string


    if theDestinationCalendar is "" then
        --do nothing
    else

        display dialog "Copy calendar events from " & theSourceCalendar & " to " & theDestinationCalendar & "?" buttons {"OK", "Cancel"} default button 2
        if the button returned of the result is "OK" then
            set TheEvents to events of calendar theSourceCalendar
            set otherEvents to events of calendar theDestinationCalendar
            repeat with anEvent in TheEvents
                set curDate to current date
                set isNew to 1
                set startDate to start date of anEvent
                set endDate to end date of anEvent
                set eventStatus to status of anEvent
                set recuInfo to recurrence of anEvent
                set auid to uid of anEvent
                if recuInfo is not missing value then
                    set ed to my getRecurrenceTermination(startDate, recuInfo)
                end if
                if endDate ≥ curDate and eventStatus is not none then
                    --check that is not already existing using uid of events
                    repeat with oEvent in otherEvents
                        set ouid to uid of oEvent
                        if ouid is equal to auid then
                            set isNew to 0
                            exit repeat
                        end if
                    end repeat
                    if isNew is not 0 then
                        duplicate anEvent to end of calendar theDestinationCalendar
                    end if
                else
                    log "Event discarded: old"
                end if

            end repeat
        else
            --do nothing
        end if
    end if
end if
end tell
```

I believe the duplicate check problem flagging, when no duplicates exist is maybe because of this?

```
set auid to uid of anEvent
```

Comment: Did you ever get it to work?